# Using SJCL library in Angular2

Tags: angular, sjcl

In my app i would like to use "Stanford Javascript Crypto Library" which has a typing and i also see https://github.com/Evgenus/sjcl-typescript-definitions.

I dont understand how i can use it in my project. How can i use the command
`sjcl.encrypt("password", "data")` in my project.

i am using angular 4, angular-cli beta 2

i have run `npm install --save-dev @types/sjcl`

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [ "sjcl" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to install **sjcl** package: `npm install --save sjcl`
 
With types (not necessary): `npm install --save sjcl @types/sjcl`

Then add import in your code where you want to use sjcl:

```
import * as sjcl from 'sjcl';
```

You don't need to add `sjcl` into tsconfig.app.json file.

---

**Important!** Also if you look into type definitions you will see they were written for sjcl **v1.0.1**, last version of sjcl is **1.0.6** so you might get type errors for some functions.